# Unreachable code after throw new System.NotImplementedException ();

Tags: c#, gtk, warnings

I have a silly question I'm super noob in gtksharp with monodevelp and i create button when click it will clear the entry text but monodevelop generate inside the click button function :

```
throw new System.NotImplementedException ();
```

and i write after it this code :

```
entry1.Text = "";
```

and when i build it i got this warning :

```
 Warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected (CS0162)
```

so what is mean the code works without this exception i want to understand the warning mean
and  if someone give me some links for basic books or document to learn how to deal with gtk# component it would really help thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the line `throw new System.NotImplementedException ();` since you have provided some implementation by setting the text to empty string.

The reason you are getting the warning: `Unreachable code detected (CS0162)` is because you are throwing the exception in the first line and then setting the text property to empty string, which will never get exectued. As far as [System.NotImplementedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notimplementedexception.aspx) is concerned, it is

> The exception that is thrown when a requested method or operation is
>   not implemented.

Comment: ahh i understand now so this only generate when there are no implementation just as reminder ok i got it now  i thought it should be there always ..thanks

Answer (score 3):

When you throw an exception the program stops and the code after will never be executed, delete the line:

```
throw new System.NotImplementedException ();
```

The remarks on the [System.Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) class gives you quite a bit of essential information how exception throwing and handling works in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

An [exception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) (i.e. error) is being thrown. When this happens, the function returns and looks up the stack for an exception handler (try/catch). If it finds one, the exception is handled and goes away. If it is not handled, the program may have to exit.

In this case, `throw new System.NotImplementedException ();` really means **create and send the error called `System.NotImplementedException()`**. When this exception is thrown, the function returns. So, nothing after it will be called. This is the source of your error.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this string from your method:

```
throw new System.NotImplementedException ();
```

Comment: but i need to know why this method generated and how remove this warning without  delete this exception thanks

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
throw new System.NotImplementedException ();
```

is auto-generated. It tells the developer that you have to fill the method with actual code rather than using an auto-generated code-block.
Just delete it and implement your method.

Answer (score 0):

Unreachable code detected means that part of your code is not going to be executed.

Since you have thrown an exception, the control will propagate downwards on the call stack  go to the level where the exception can be handled.